# I have some quite simple SQL that I can trying to change to either Linq or LLBLGEN

Tags: sql, linq, inner-join, llblgenpro

I want to do something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.* 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.ID1 = T1.ID1
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.ID2 = T2.ID2
--FOLLOWING CAN BE ADDED MULTIPLE TIMES  (LOOPS IN C#?)
INNER JOIN T2 AS T2A ON T3.ID2 = T2A.ID2
INNER JOIN T1 AS T1A ON T1A.ID1 = T2A.ID1
--END MULTI
WHERE T1.ID1 = 1
AND T3.ID3 = 2
AND T3.ID4 = 3
--THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS WILL ALSO BE FOR EVERY SET OF EXTRA JOINS (LOOPS IN C#?)
AND T1A.ID1 = 4
AND T1I.ID5 = 5
--END MULTI
```

...in either Linq or LLBLGen Code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the LLBGen I have so far...

```
            IPredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression();
            filter.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.OptionId == dl.Key);
            filter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationFields.ProductTypeId == DataSource.DataItem.ProductTypeId);
            filter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationFields.ProductId == DataSource.ProductID);
            bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(filter);

            bucket.Relations.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeEntity.Relations.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationProfileEntityUsingProductTypeOptionAttributeId, JoinHint.Inner);
            bucket.Relations.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationProfileEntity.Relations.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationEntityUsingProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationId, JoinHint.Inner);

            var filtered = _dropdowns.Where(k => ((DropDownList)k.Value[1]).SelectedValue != "-1" && k.Key != dl.Key);
            foreach (var filteredDdl in filtered)
            {

                IPredicateExpression subFilter = new PredicateExpression();
                subFilter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.AttributeId == int.Parse(((DropDownList)filteredDdl.Value[1]).SelectedValue));
                subFilter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.OptionId == filteredDdl.Key);
                bucket.PredicateExpression.AddWithAnd(subFilter);                    
            }


            ProductTypeOptionAttributeCollection attrs = new ProductTypeOptionAttributeCollection();
            attrs.GetMulti(bucket.PredicateExpression, -1, null, bucket.Relations);
```

And here is the actual query I want...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT PTOA.* 
    FROM ProductTypeOptionAttribute AS PTOA
    INNER JOIN ProductTypeOPtionAttributeCombinationProfile AS PTOACP ON PTOACP.ProductTypeOPtionAttributeID = PTOA.AttributeID
    INNER JOIN ProductTypeOPtionAttributeCombination AS PTOAC ON PTOAC.CombinationID = PTOACP.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationID
    --FOLLOWING CAN BE ADDED MULTIPLE TIMES  (LOOPS IN C#?)
    INNER JOIN ProductTypeOPtionAttributeCombinationProfile AS PTOACP2 ON PTOAC.CombinationID = PTOACP2.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationID
    INNER JOIN ProductTypeOPtionAttribute AS PTOA2 ON PTOACP2.ProductTypeOPtionAttributeID = PTOA2.AttributeID
--END MULTI
    WHERE PTOA.OptionID = 59
    AND PTOAC.ProductTypeID = 11

AND PTOAC.ProductID = 218
--THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS WILL ALSO BE FOR EVERY SET OF EXTRA JOINS (LOOPS IN C#?)
AND PTOA2.AttributeID = 42
AND PTOA2.OptionID = 58
--END MULTI
```

Cheers

Comment: Suggestion: Import your database into the Entity Framework designer, post the diagram.  If you have FKs it will be easy to just navigate the entity relationships created for you to model this query.

Comment: Added some more detail, hope it helps. Apologies for the long table names!!!

Answer (score 1):

LLBLGen Tips:

- Use SQL Server Profiler to view the SQL emitted (set a breakpoint right after your call to GetMulti, then watch your trace)
- You have a lot of complicated UI login and cast/converts that could fail -- my personal preference would be to move those to separate code
- You don't need JoinHint.Inner as that is the default
- (Personal preference) use a RelationCollection instead of the bucket.

I don't entirely understand your situation (especially the multiple joins to the same table?), but this may work.  I think you want subFilter.AddWithOr instead of .AddWithAnd.

```
    IPredicateExpression filter = new PredicateExpression();
    filter.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.OptionId == dl.Key);
    filter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationFields.ProductTypeId == DataSource.DataItem.ProductTypeId);
    filter.AddWithAnd(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationFields.ProductId == DataSource.ProductID);

    IRelationCollection relations = new RelationCollection();
    relations.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeEntity.Relations.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationProfileEntityUsingProductTypeOptionAttributeId);
    relations.Add(ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationProfileEntity.Relations.ProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationEntityUsingProductTypeOptionAttributeCombinationId);

    var filtered = _dropdowns.Where(k => ((DropDownList)k.Value[1]).SelectedValue != "-1" && k.Key != dl.Key);
    foreach (var filteredDdl in filtered)
    {
        IPredicateExpression subFilter = new PredicateExpression();
        subFilter.AddWithOr(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.AttributeId == int.Parse(((DropDownList)filteredDdl.Value[1]).SelectedValue));
        subFilter.AddWithOr(ProductTypeOptionAttributeFields.OptionId == filteredDdl.Key);
        filter.AddWithAnd(subFilter);
    }

    ProductTypeOptionAttributeCollection attrs = new ProductTypeOptionAttributeCollection();
    attrs.GetMulti(filter, relations)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic SQL query you presented should be faily easy to reproduce in LINQ.

From t in T1
Where T1.ID == 1
Select;

if your not already using it download the free LINQPAD http://www.linqpad.net/ Its got loads of examples to get you up to speed.